# php setAttribute replacing & with &amp;

Tags: php

I'm trying to do somwthing like this (where $doc is a DOMDocument)

```
$link_found = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');

foreach ($link_found as $idx => $link) {
    $link->setAttribute('href', "/test.php?t=1&q=2" ) ;
}
```

All is working, but in the href now I got

```
"/test.php?t=1&amp;q=2"
```

I need the literal `&`, not encoded in `&amp;`

I need

```
 "/test.php?t=1&q=2"
```

Like a common query string

Comment: That'd be invalid HTML. You cannot generate invalid HTML with DOM functions. It's a feature, not a bug.

Comment: ? It's a normal query string... 
Like google: 
http://www.google.it/#hl=it&sclient=psy-ab&q=example

Comment: Maybe try using html_entity_decode? http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standards require that `&` be escaped if it is not introducing an entity, *even if* it is in an attribute.

(That's got to be the most `i_` words I've used in a single sentence... ever...)

Comment: Correct. You type `&amp;` but it means `&`. The URL is by no means mangled.

Comment: Damn...i have not tried the link... i supposed it was not working but it's working ... thanks to Alvaro G. Vicario !!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = html_entity_decode($string); // you're welcome
```

Comment: I was considering whether to downvote this answer for the mere fact of providing a way to generate invalid HTML on purpose, then realised that it just cannot work. How exactly do you decode entities in the context of DOM functions?

Comment: i would not @ÁlvaroG.Vicario maby my answer was misunderstood. that would not make any sense and appears not to be possible with domdocument functions. i merley thought the questioner wants to work with such strings extracted at a later point. for visualization purposes or such...